# Creating dynamic maps based on updated attributes in SHP file

Tags: qgis, geoserver, shapefile, fields-attributes

I am new to GIS. I can create maps and do basic transformation of the SHP file using QGIS. I also succesfully applied formatting based on attributes. I am able to add new attributes to SHP file in QGIS, and I have published my map with styles to my instance of Geoserver (SLD styling compatibility is painful). It's all working fine. 
I've also familarized myself with kartograph.py
*note: I am only using free software*

My workflow is:
I get SHP file for my country with counties. I then add new CSV layer containing KEY matching the attributes in CSV file with the attributes in SHP file. ( I do this to add some numeric data to Counties). Then I will add some styling to counties based on the new attributes and export to new SHP file. 
I then publish this to GeoServer, correct the styling and I am done - I can see my data on the map via webservice.

**The question:** 
I am able to generate CSV with new data regularly (e.g. daily) but adding the updated attributes to shapefile and then publishing to geoserve, correcting the SLD style manualy everyday seems very troublesome. I feel there must be better way.

I am wondering how some of you Experts tackle this issue?

Is my workflow/approach incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

Try using qgis2web (leaflet) plugin. I think that is the asy way to solve your problem. Dynamics that require one or two refresh by hour can be solved in linux using crontab and shel script that run qgis in command line mode.